# Responsive centered div different view in mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm not sure how I can explain this the best. 
but I'm working on a layout right now, and I've created an okay code.
However when I test the website the 3 DIV's I did create show up different in the mobile layout then in the PC layout.

Well here is the mobile code

```
.container1 {
margin:  5px auto;
width: 98%;
text-align:center;
}

.container1 > div {
width: 100%;
}
.col1 {
float: auto;

}
.col2 {
float: auto;

}
.col3 {
margin: auto;

}

div.panel {
width: 100%;

}
```

And this is the PC CODE

```
.container1 {
margin:  5px auto;
width: 98%;
text-align:center;
}

.container1 > div {
width: 33%;
}
.col1 {
float: left;

}
.col2 {
float: right;

}
.col3 {
margin: auto;

}

div.panel {
 width: 100%;

}
```

HTML IS:

```
<div class="container1">
<div class="col1"></div>
<div class="col2"></div>
<div class="col3"></div>
</div>
```

However, the mobile version shows them as
Col1 - Col3 - Col2

So I'm not sure how to fix this that mobile also shows it as col1,col2,col3.
If I move the div, it doesn't show good in the PC version.

I hope someone can help out.

So, it are 3 div's horizontally aligned.

Comment: why are you making the divs `width: 100%;` if you want them to be horizontally aligned? - Change it to 33%. And set them to `float: left`.

Comment: Please don't add "solved," or variants thereof, to your question titles, instead mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted (by clicking the tick mark beside the appropriate answer, you can only accept one answer). If no answer solved your problem, and you solved it yourself, then please post an answer to your question explaining your solution, and accept that answer when the countdown ends (two days, I think). If your solution can't be understood without additional context and information, then please also edit your question to add the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `float: auto`.  Simply make them all `float: left` in the mobile version. Then they will appear in the order they are in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this use `display: flex;` property to the parent element, and we have an property called `order` give to the child element with this we can achieve easily your requirement.

[working codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/ALyBQo)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the mobile:

```
.container1 {
margin:  5px auto;
width: 98%;
text-align:center;
}

.container1 > div {
width: 100%;
}
.col1 {
float: left;

}
.col2 {
float: left;

}
.col3 {
margin: auto;

}

div.panel {
width: 100%;

}
```

[float have no auto property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

in the end this is my CSS and HTML which is working

```
.card {
box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0,255,24,0.3);
transition: 0.3s;
float: left;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color:#111;
width: 97%;
}

.container1 {
padding-top: 5px;
margin:  0px auto;
width: 98%;
text-align:center;
}

.container1 > div {
width: 33%;
}

.col1 {
float: left;
}

.col2 {
float: right;
}

.col3 {
margin: auto;
}

div.panel {
width: 100%;
}
```

Also HTML:

```
<div class="container1">
<div class="col1 ">
<div class="card " id="left">
</div></div>

<div class="col3 ">
<div class="card " id="center">
</div></div>

<div class="col2 ">
<div class="card " id="right">
</div></div>
</div>
```